# Looking for a book about a young woman abandoned on an empty planet, which turned out to have aliens; archaeological theme

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a book about a young woman abandoned (possibly by accident) on a planet thought to be lacking sentient life; this story also had a distinct archaeological theme. Therefore, there may have been significant ruins, and the planet may not have been as lacking in sentient life as was first thought.

I recall finding this standard sized paperback in an old library's sci-fi and fantasy carousel, I didn't happen to have a card for that region, and that library was not on the intra-library system either. I took a note of the title, but have since lost it. I no longer live in that region, either.

I seem to have recollected that the book cover had a building on it (of tan colored stone?), and a young woman or girl as well (in blue, maybe?) depicted. I think she was part of an archaeological expedition or something related.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Do you have a approximate publication date, any other information?

Comment: Sadly, no. I cannot even recall the time period I found it with certainty.

Comment: Managed to pull up a hazy recall of the cover, possibly. added it to the question in any case.

Comment: What were the sentient's  like, do you recall?

Comment: Since I didn't have a library card for that system, I couldn't check it out. Never was able to read it. I could be wrong about the sentients. Possibly, she was later recovered and claimed aliens, true or not. I'm going of my hazy memories of the back cover blurb.

Comment: But for the age difference of the protagonist, your description reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remnant_Population by Elizabeth Moon.